# Modify OS X app without source code using Swift

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

The problem is the following.

The title for button FindName is wrong and it should be Search, another thing is that window title is misspelled: "DisplayUsrEmail"

I don't have the source code of the application.

My main requirement is to write the small application that will modify the current application and fix above problems.

I have to write the new app using Swift.

**What I did:**

1) It is quite simple to change the title of the button without coding. (FindName -> Search) I changed it in the Info.plist file.

2) It is also easy to change the app title (Executable file) in the Info.plist, but in my case, it doesn't change the window's title "DisplayUsrEmail"

3) I opened the apps unix executable file in the hex editor (used https://hexed.it/) and found there the title "DisplayUsrEmail". But the app crashes when I add the byte with symbol 'e'. ("DisplayUsrEmail" -> "DisplayUserEmail") I can just change the title with the same characters count, but it doesn't resolve my problem.

So, is it possible to write the new app that will modify the current one? If yes, what is the workflow?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app is compiled through xcode and is a known fact that it is not possible to retrieve the source code from the compiled application.

To answer your question: no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is at all possible. When an app is built, it's also codesigned to prevent any changes to it. If any changes are made, macOS can't (or refuses to) open the app. This is a security feature that prevents people from modifying applications to bypass security measures, licensing, etc. in the app. Since you've modified the app, you are seeing this security feature in action in the form of the app crashing when you attempt to launch it.

That being said, it MIGHT be possible to modify the UI elements only without affecting the executable. In the app's resources folder, there should be a file with a ".nib" extension. This is the compiled user interface which is where the incorrect spelling of the window and button are. If you modify this file ONLY, the UI elements might be correct when you launch the app again. It's also possible that this nib file is part of the codesigned bundle and modifying it will cause a crash, just as if you'd modified the executable.